# Solving a triangle using the given equation

Tags: triangles

In a triangle $ABC$ $2a^2+4b^2+c^2=4ab+2ac$ then the numerical value of $cos B$ equals ?

($a,b,c$ are sides opposite to angles $A,B,C$)

I tried to use cosine rule , but couldn't adjust terms accordingly, using the given equation.

Any hints / Solutions are welcome.

Answer: $7/8$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$2a^2+4b^2+c^2=4ab+2ac\iff (a-2b)^2+(a-c)^2=0$$

Now sum of squares of two real numbers is zero, so each must be individually zero.
Hence $a=c=2b$. Then
$$
\cos B=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}=\frac{4b^2+4b^2-b^2}{8b^2}=\frac{7}{8}.
$$

Comment: Got it . For some reason I can only accept after 2 minutes :)

Comment: @impartialmale, not sure why you have not left anything to the OP. Here, we are not committed to purvey a complete solution

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: Since I give the process of calculating $\cos B$, we posted our solution 5 seconds late than you :D

Comment: @impartialmale, May I request you not to edit my solutions in future just to complete the solution

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Okie. Just kidding!!! Sorry to make you annoyed...

Answer (score 0):

Since $a^2+c^2\geq 2ac$ and $a^2+4b^2\geq 4ab$ (Cauchy's inequality) and so from the given equality we have
$$
a=c \quad \text{and} \quad a=2b.
$$
Then
$$
\cos B=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}=\frac{4b^2+4b^2-b^2}{8b^2}=\frac{7}{8}.
$$